# android unable to start Main activity in options menu

Tags: java, android, android-activity, program-entry-point, android-optionsmenu

Hi there basically i have created a options menu and have one of the menu items as the home button which essentially calls the home activity Main.java. I have used the code

startActivity(new Intent("org.me.myandroidstuff.Main"));

in a GetHome method. My problem is that when i run this the application crashes because it isnt handled. Now i know this generally means there is some error in the androidmanifest file however i think my coding is okay so im a bit stumped. Here is my androidmanifest.xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.me.myandroidstuff"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="false">

**<activity
android:name=".Main"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>**

<activity
android:name=".PetrolPriceActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="org.me.myandroidstuff.PetrolPriceActivity" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
android:name=".AreaURL"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="org.me.myandroidstuff.AreaURL" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

the part highlighted is the code for my main class. Im rather new to android so i imagine its a relatively simple fix but ive looked and i havent found a solution yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use    `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class));`

Comment: sorry i take that back i made a syntax error this has actually worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

change the code to

`startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));`

In manifest file in action you have written

*< action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />*

while calling the new Intent(String Action), you need to put the same action name.

or you can use different signature of constructor,
change the code to

`startActivity(new Intent(this, Main.class);`

in place of "this" you can use the appropriate context.

Comment: no sorry this didnt work. I am getting a ActivityNotFoundException whenever i try

Comment: In which activity you have created the options menu. Can you please add some details.

Comment: i created a Menu activity and then extended it to all my other activities. However the main activity problem has been around this the start and ive never been able to solve it

Comment: i believe it must have something to do with my androidmanifest since i am getting a ActivityNotFound Exception

Comment: you can try removing intent-filters from activities except launcher activity.
intent-filters are for defining implicit intents, if you are not using intentionally i suppose.

Comment: sorry could u explain intent filters more pls

Comment: can you comment out startActivity line, and try to run the app. 
check if options other than home working fine?

Comment: sorry this question has been answered now. The first answer worked

Comment: but yes the other option ive coded are working thanks